# MySQL updating duplicate IDs based on match and no match criteria all in one table

Tags: mysql

Hopefully I can explain this clearly.  I have a table that has what need to be unique IDs for people within a group.  The IDs are generated using first 3 letters of the first name and date of birth.  Normally, with smaller groups (less than 500) this works fine.  However in large groups we do hit upon some duplicates.  We'd then just append a -1, -2, -3 etc. to any duplicate IDs.  For example:

```
ID    GROUP          UID            FIRST_NAME
1     123456         ALE19900123    ALEXIS
2     123456         ALE19900123    ALEXANDER
3     123456         ALE19900123    ALEJANDRO
4     789789         ALE19900123    ALEX
```

What I'd like to do is for ID 2 and 3 append a -1 and -2 respectively to their UID field so that 1,2 and 3 are now unique (GROUP + UID).  ID 4 would be ignored because the GROUP is different

I've started with something like this:

```
UPDATE table A
  JOIN table B
    ON B.GROUP = A.GROUP
   AND B.UID = A.UID
   AND B.FIRST_NAME <> A.FIRST_NAME
   AND B.ID < A.ID
   SET A.duplicate_record = 1;
```

That should set the duplicate_record field = 1 for IDs 2 and 3.  But then I still need to append a -1, -2, -3 etc. to those UIDs and I'm not sure how to do that.  Maybe instead of just setting a flag = 1 for duplicate I should set the count of records that are duplicates?

Comment: Perhaps it would be simple to parse the ID, to check for the appendation. If it exists, just cast it as an int and add 1, re-append and update. And, of course, if it does not exist, you can just append 1.

Comment: Why not *always* append ID, which will guarantee that UID will always be unique regardless of group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `group, UID` tuple is unique (and it should be), why not `insert ignore` the first one (without any value appended), check for how many rows were affected by `SELECT ROW_COUNT();`, and if that is zero, append `-1`? If you put it in a for cycle (pseudocode):

```
while i < 1000 do
    insert ignore into people (group, uid, first_name) values (123456, concat(their_uid, "-", i), first name);
    if ((select row_count();) == 1):
        break;
    i=i+1;
end while;
```

Comment: I tagged that as accepted since it's pretty close to what I did outside of MySql.  I just wrote a quick script that can be fired off to parse through these IDs and append the correct -1, -2 etc.  Thanks!